# Create a PhotoImage with a C++ Buffer using: Python 3.3, Python.Boost and Tkinter

Tags: c++, python, tkinter, boost-python

I am using Tkinter and python.boost on python 3.3.

I want to create a simple gui that shows an image at the center. The image is stored in a C++ class using double values. In order to show an image using tkinter I have to create a **PhotoImage** object.

I have read that it is possible to create a PhotoImage object using the method **Image.fromstring(mode, size, data, decoder, parameters)**. What I think is: if I create a function that converts my buffer into a std::string I will we able to create a PhotoImage object.

My C++ class is:

```
class DoubleImage
{
    double* m_dBuffer; // Values from 0 to 1

public:
    DoubleImage(const char* fileName, const int width, const int height);

    /* Class Functions  */

    std::string toString( void ) {
        double *pSrc  = m_dBuffer;
        int size = getWidth() * getHeight() * getChannels();

        char* buffer = new char[size];
        char* pbuffer = buffer;

        for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++pSrc, ++pbuffer ) {
            *pbuffer = ((char) (*pSrc * 255.0));
        }

        std::string ret(buffer);

        delete[] buffer;

        return ret;
    }
};
```

And the python boost code is:

```
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ImageModule)
{

    class_<DoubleImage>("DoubleImage", init<const char*, const int, const int>()) 
        .add_property("width", &DoubleImage::getWidth)
        .add_property("height", &DoubleImage::getHeight)
        .add_property("channels", &DoubleImage::getChannels)
        // Some functions ...
        .def("toString", &DoubleImage::toString)
    ; 
}
```

But when I run toString in python it get this error:

```
>>> from ImageModule import *
>>> img = DoubleImage('001.png', 300, 200)
>>> buffer = img.toString()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 155: invalid start byte
>>>
```

I have two questions, first what I am missing?? and second once I have solved this error, which parameters I have to use to create a PhotoImage object?

Comment: I tried to put the end character '\0' at the end of the string but do not work ... I gave the same result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution after suffering a lot :P

First the function *toString* have to be changed like this:

```
std::string DoubleImage::toString( void ) {
    ECV_CHECK_ERROR ( m_eType == IT_UKNOWN, "The image is not initialized!" );

    double *pSrc  = (double *) m_cvImage.data;
    long size = getWidth() * getHeight() * getChannels();

    std::string ret(size, ' ');

    for ( long i = 0; i < size; ++i, ++pSrc ) {
         ret[i] = ((char) (*pSrc * 255.0));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

otherwise, the resultant std::string wont have the total length (because the constructor search for the first '\0'). In addition the strange error "**UnicodeDecodeError**", only apears using python 3.3. By using python 2.7 the problem is solved. So that, I recommend using python 2.7 for image processing.

Then I have installed the [PIL module](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) (also only available on python 2.7). Then in python I create the PhotoImage object using this code:

```
>>> from ImageModule import *
>>> from PIL import image
>>> from ImageTk import PhotoImage
>>> img = DoubleImage('001.png', 300, 200)
>>> buffer = img.toString()
>>> img_pil = Image.fromstring('RGB', [300, 200], buffer, 'raw', 'BGR', 300 * 3, 0)
>>> tk_image = PhotoImage(img_pil)
```

where 300 is the image with, 200 the image height, RGB the ouput format, BGR the input format (IplImage) and 3 are the channels (3 * 300 the image step). Then all work like a charm :)

Comment: change python is a b big project.